# anonymous cifs client can't read files created with nfs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nfs

I'm sharing a windows folder using both nfs and a windows share. The windows share has read permissions for `Everyone`. The nfs share has write permissions (with "Allow root access") for a specific host.

I created a couple of files and folders with different owners and groups including `root` and `4294967294` and unix permissions 777, but a windows client cannot read them.

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 distuser 4294967294   64 Apr 20 09:47 /mnt
drwxrwxrwx 2 distuser 4294967294 4096 Apr 20 09:57 /mnt/distr
```

I can list the contents of `/mnt`, but not `/mnt/distr` from a windows client.

After creating a directory using nfs, the security tab shows explicit permissions for: `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`, and some unresolvable SIDs.

Can I map the traditional unix scope "others" to NTFS "Everyone"?

Currently I have the following:

```
C:\pub>icacls after
after S-1-5-88-3-504:(N)
      S-1-5-88-1-0:(F)
      S-1-5-88-2-0:(RX,W,DC)
      S-1-5-88-4:(Rc,S,REA,RA)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
      BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
```

`S-1-5-88-4` is the `SID` currently mapped to `others`.